# Mongoose and multiple database in single node.js project

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I'm doing a Node.js project that contains sub projects. One sub project will have one Mongodb database and Mongoose will be use for wrapping and querying db. But the problem is

- Mongoose doesn't allow to use multiple databases in single mongoose instance as the models are build on one connection.
- To use multiple mongoose instances, Node.js doesn't allow multiple module instances as it has caching system in `require()`. I know disable module caching in Node.js but I think it is not the good solution as it is only need for mongoose.

  I've tried to use `createConnection()` and `openSet()` in mongoose, but it was not the solution.

  I've tried to deep copy the mongoose instance (http://blog.imaginea.com/deep-copy-in-javascript/) to pass new mongoose instances to the sub project, but it throwing `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

I want to know is there anyways to use multiple database with mongoose or any workaround for this problem? Because I think mongoose is quite easy and fast. Or any other modules as recommendations?

Comment: [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYlfruqx_S8) is a good reference for connecting to multiple databases. Although it's in Hindi, you can follow along with the code in the video.

Comment: a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53951290/6908282) which talks about the difference between `connect` and `createconnection`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

One thing you can do is, you might have subfolders for each projects. So, install mongoose in that subfolders and require() mongoose from own folders in each sub applications. Not from the project root or from global. So one sub project, one mongoose installation and one mongoose instance.

```
-app_root/
--foo_app/
---db_access.js
---foo_db_connect.js
---node_modules/
----mongoose/
--bar_app/
---db_access.js
---bar_db_connect.js
---node_modules/
----mongoose/
```

In foo_db_connect.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/foo_db');
module.exports = exports = mongoose;
```

In bar_db_connect.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/bar_db');
module.exports = exports = mongoose;
```

In db_access.js files

```
var mongoose = require("./foo_db_connect.js"); // bar_db_connect.js for bar app
```

Now, you can access multiple databases with mongoose.

Comment: This means that every project will have its own connection. You will not be able to manage 100k connections. I think it would be better to use `useDb` command which uses the same connection pool.

Comment: xpepermint are you able to show an example for useDb -- I am having this issue currently http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37583198/how-do-i-use-mongoose-to-connect-to-two-different-databases?noredirect=1#comment62655639_37583198

Comment: This looks like a huge burden on the project. don't you think so?

Comment: Having a few different connection instances (e.g. for a User DB, a Session DB, and for application data) per application is absolutely fine. It's not 'a huge burden' or going to cause scaling problems and is a common use case.

Comment: You are the best my friend! thanks so much! it works for me! thanks!

Comment: But as this does not have await, i cant stop my server if connection to mongo did not happen.

Answer (score 271):

According to [the fine manual](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections), `createConnection()` *can* be used to connect to multiple databases.

However, you need to create separate models for each connection/database:

```
var conn      = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/testA');
var conn2     = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/testB');

// stored in 'testA' database
var ModelA    = conn.model('Model', new mongoose.Schema({
  title : { type : String, default : 'model in testA database' }
}));

// stored in 'testB' database
var ModelB    = conn2.model('Model', new mongoose.Schema({
  title : { type : String, default : 'model in testB database' }
}));
```

I'm pretty sure that you can share the schema between them, but you have to check to make sure.

Comment: Yes, named connections and a shared schema are the way to go I think. Each connection will need a unique model as per Robert's example.

Comment: Also checkout `useDb()` available in 3.8 to share the underlying connection pool: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/wiki/3.8-Release-Notes#connection-pool-sharing

Comment: Suppose I have auto-generated database (Say n number of database). Not one or two. Is there any way to connect to these without creating separate model for each database ?

Comment: @AnoojKrishnanG I don't think that's possible, no. You need to create the model against each database separately. However, as I already stated in my answer, you may be able to share the *schema's* amongst the connections, which may save some coding time.

Comment: Is this is the only way to connect multiple database at same time ?

Comment: @AnoojKrishnanG you can also use `useDb()`, as @aaronheckmann already mentioned. That way, you can open multiple database connections through the same connection pool.

Comment: is there anyway to create two mongoose connections with single model?

Comment: @gvsharma to the same database? Mongoose already maintains a pool of (concurrent) connections (5 by default, I believe) to the database.

Comment: No it is not the same database..i have two databases. I need to get the data from old database and insert that to new database. Here old and new databases will have some common fields.

Comment: @gvsharma in that case, AFAIK you still need to create two separate models, one for each database. The schema for each model can probably be the same.

Comment: @AnoojKrishnanG I am facing a similar problem of auto-generating databases for each of my clients. Did you find any solution regarding this?

Comment: You can share the schema across the different models, and therefore DBs. `var newSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ ... })`, `var model2 = conn1.model('newModel', newSchema)`, `var model2 = conn2.model('newModel', newSchema)`

Comment: I've tried like above. there is no error. but when I try to modelName.find({}).then(data => {}), data is empty array.

Comment: oh, that's my fault. this method works fine. Thank you so much.

Comment: Note that mongoose.createConnection is asynchronous. Use asyc/await or .then().catch() format

Comment: via createConnection on a hobby dyno of Heroku with MongoDB atlas

Comment: @ArnavSingh and how many databases were you able to connect to?

Comment: I am working on an open-source alternative to Firebase, it provides firebase like client-side abstraction for MongoDB. So far it is working well with 10 databases. I am wondering if there any kind of limitation on how many connections a server can make and what is that limit? https://github.com/itsarnavsingh/upon.one

Comment: @ArnavSingh I doubt this is going to scale well, at least with Mongoose. There are probably limits, but those will be relatively high (say 8000 or 16000 connections).

Comment: Thank you so much for the info, can u please give me a link to the documentation reference?

Answer (score 100):

Pretty late but this might help someone. The current answers assumes you are using the same file for your connections and models.

In real life, there is a high chance that you are splitting your models into different files. You can use something like this in your main file:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/default');

const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', () => {
  console.log('connected');
});
```

which is just how it is described in the docs. And then in your model files, do something like the following:

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

const userInfoSchema = new Schema({
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: new Date(),
  },
  // ...other fields
});

const myDB = mongoose.connection.useDb('myDB');

const UserInfo = myDB.model('userInfo', userInfoSchema);

export default UserInfo;
```

Where myDB is your database name.

Comment: Thank you - I was able to use 3 different databases within a single application using:

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const mySchema = new Schema ({});

const mydbvar = mongoose.connection.useDb('mydb')  
module.exports = mydbvar.model('myCollection', MySchema);

Comment: Definitely the best and most real-world example. Connect to the default db (just like if you were using something like SQL Server) and then take advantage of useDb to target your DML at the appropriate database. (Very helpful for keeping your users in one db and your data in another.) No need to start making multiple connections when ultimately you are sending requests to the same server. Now, if you were connecting to two different servers, that's a different kettle of fish.

Comment: As @Wade said, as far as I understand this solution only works when all of the databases are on the same server. It's not clear if this answers the OP's question and IMO is a bit misleading.

Comment: This is just what I needed for MongoDB Atlas migration from `test`, and also to avoid having multiple connections. However, I also `.db` at the end (`const v1 = mongoose.connection.useDb('test').db`) as the old db doesn't need to be mongoose managed.

Comment: Seems great when db's are in the same server... Is there a similar approach when db's are in differents hosts?

Comment: @Miquel The [mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multi-tenant-connections) explain two patterns for multi-tenant connections.

Answer (score 49):

As an alternative approach, Mongoose does export a constructor for a new instance on the default instance. So something like this is possible.

```
var Mongoose = require('mongoose').Mongoose;

var instance1 = new Mongoose();
instance1.connect('foo');

var instance2 = new Mongoose();
instance2.connect('bar');
```

This is very useful when working with separate data sources, and also when you want to have a separate database context for each user or request. You will need to be careful, as it is possible to create a LOT of connections when doing this. Make sure to call disconnect() when instances are not needed, and also to limit the pool size created by each instance.

Comment: is this another way to writing ['Above Answer'](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19475259/3050426) ?

Comment: This is not the above answer, it's better. The above answer installs multiple copies of Mongoose, unnecessarily.

Comment: how would i make queries using this method?

Comment: `await instance1.connection.collection('foo').insert({
    foo: 'bar',
  })
  await instance2.connection.collection('foo').insert({
    foo: 'zoo',
  })`

Comment: In fact better working in my case since I have completely different credentials for each connection, let alone models and databases.

Comment: yes worked like a charm ... this is exactly what i was looking for !!! also used                       module.exports = instance1.model("tableName", TableSchema); module.exports = instance2.model("tableName", TableSchema);to create models in respective databases

Answer (score 7):

**Mongoose and multiple database in single node.js project**

use **useDb** to solve this issue

example

```
//product databse 
const myDB = mongoose.connection.useDb('product');
module.exports = myDB.model("Snack", snackSchema);
//user databse
const myDB = mongoose.connection.useDb('user');
module.exports = myDB.model("User", userSchema);
```

Comment: This should be the best solution. Utilize one connection to access multiple database

Answer (score 2):

*A bit optimized(for me atleast) solution.* write this to a file db.js and require this to wherever required and call it with a function call and you are good to go.

```
   const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    async function getConnections(url,db){
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true },function(err, client) {
                if(err) { console.error(err) 
                    resolve(false);
                }
                else{
                    resolve(client.db(db));
                }
            })
        });
    }

    module.exports = async function(){
        let dbs      = [];
        dbs['db1']     = await getConnections('mongodb://localhost:27017/','db1');
        dbs['db2']     = await getConnections('mongodb://localhost:27017/','db2');
        return dbs;
    };
```

Comment: how can I create a modal using this way ?

Answer (score 1):

I have been using this method and it works great for me until now.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

function makeNewConnection(uri) {
    const db = mongoose.createConnection(uri, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    });

    db.on('error', function (error) {
        console.log(`MongoDB :: connection ${this.name} ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
        db.close().catch(() => console.log(`MongoDB :: failed to close connection ${this.name}`));
    });

    db.on('connected', function () {
        mongoose.set('debug', function (col, method, query, doc) {
            console.log(`MongoDB :: ${this.conn.name} ${col}.${method}(${JSON.stringify(query)},${JSON.stringify(doc)})`);
        });
        console.log(`MongoDB :: connected ${this.name}`);
    });

    db.on('disconnected', function () {
        console.log(`MongoDB :: disconnected ${this.name}`);
    });

    return db;
}

// Use

const db1 = makeNewConnection(MONGO_URI_DB1);
const db2 = makeNewConnection(MONGO_URI_DB2);

module.exports = {
   db1,
   db2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help anyone, but it is what I ended up doing after attempting to chase down handling multiple connections using Mongoose, and ending up here (from numerous locations).

The object returned by `const mongoose = require("mongoose");` (re. Mongoose v.8) has a 'connections' property, an array of connections. This in turn contains an id property, the id of the array, which is returned when the connection is made.

So I did something like this:

```
// db001URL is the MongoDB connection URL, with optional database
const db001conn = await mongoose.createConnection(db001URL).asPromise();
console.log("connected to db001conn");
// set id variable into something: here I used a closure
mongoID({ db001: db001conn.id });
    
    
// db002URL is a different MongoDB connection string
const db002conn = await mongoose.createConnection(db002URL).asPromise();
console.log("connected to db002");
// set id variable into something: here I used a closure
mongoID({ db002: db002conn.id });
```

Storing the id allowed me to recall one of multiple connections using `mongoose.connections[id]`, which also meant I could leave the Mongoose object as mutable, and move on with my life without worry.