# Mongoose authenticationDatabase in Mongo 2.6

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have databases **A**, **B**, **C**, in addition to system's **admin**

I want to add a user that has *readWrite* access to **A**, **B**, **C**.

```
// attempt 1
use admin
db.createUser({ user: "Bob", pwd: "1234", roles: [
    { role: "readWriteAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }
] })
```

.

```
// attempt 2
use admin
db.createUser({ user: "Bob", pwd: "1234", roles: [
    { role: "readWrite", db: "A" },
    { role: "readWrite", db: "B" },
    { role: "readWrite", db: "C" }
] })
```

For these attempts, the user is stored in db **admin**. So how can I authenticate using **admin** but perform actions in one of **A**, **B**, **C**?

```
var uri = 'mongodb://localhost/A';
var opts = {
    user: 'Bob',
    pass: '1234',
    auth: { authDb: 'admin' }
};
mongoose.connect(uri, opts); // auth fails
```

Is my only solution to separately add a user on each of **A**, **B**, **C** ? Ex.

```
use A
db.createUser({...})
use B
db.createUser({...})
use C
db.createUser({...})
```

Seems foolish.

Comment: Very late, but it's possible your auth was failing because `authDb` should be `authdb`. I tried `authDb` and got auth failed, then `authdb` and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

Easiest way is to specify authSource in the uri

```
const uri = 'mongodb://monguser:mongpass@192.168.2.2:27017/ps?authSource=admin';
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to use one Mongoose connection per database.
Have a look to [Mongoose and multiple database in single node.js project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474712/mongoose-and-multiple-database-in-single-node-js-project) .