# Mongoose how to be connected to many database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, multiple-databases

For a project, I need to switch between some MongoDB databases for doing some queries.

I found some exemple like that one : [Mongoose and multiple database in single node.js project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474712/mongoose-and-multiple-database-in-single-node-js-project)

His answer is perfectly working but now I'm trying to do it in a loop and unfortunally it's not work, I get this error:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/user/test_many_db_mongodb/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:549:74)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/user/test_many_db_mongodb/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:150:15)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/user/test_many_db_mongodb/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:533:10)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:440:14
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

And I don't understand why I get this error, if the example in the link above work my code should too:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

for (var i = 0; i != 1000; i++) {
    var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/test' + i);

    conn.on('connected', function() {
        console.log('Mongoose connected to database');

        var Model    = conn.model('Model', new mongoose.Schema({
            title : { type : String, default : 'model in test database' }
        }));

        var newModelA = new Model();
        newModelA.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
            console.log('save A');
        });
    });
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help.

I tried both way but it didn't work on my project, probably because I didn't show you all the code. I found a way using [useDb()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#drivers_node-mongodb-native_connection_NativeConnection-useDb):

```
var amqp = require('amqp');

var MailParser = require('mailparser').MailParser;
var mailparser = new MailParser();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost');

var count = 1;

var connection = amqp.createConnection({host: 'localhost'});

    connection.on('ready', function() {
        connection.queue('task_queue', {autoDelete: false,
                                        durable: true}, function(queue) {

            console.log('Waiting for emails. To exit press CTRL+C');

            queue.subscribe({ack: true, prefetchCount: 1}, function(message, headers, deliveryInfo, ack) {
                mailparser.write(message.data.toString('utf-8'));
                mailparser.end();

                ack.acknowledge();
            });
        });
    });

mailparser.on("end", function(email_object){
    var d = new Date(); // just for be sure the db name is unique for the test
    var db = conn.useDb('test_'+d.getDate()+'-'+d.getMonth()+'-'+d.getYear()+'_'+d.getHours()+'-'+d.getMinutes()+'-'+d.getSeconds()+'-'+d.getMilliseconds());

    var Model    = conn.model('Model', new mongoose.Schema({
            subject : { type : String },
            body : { type : String }
        }));
    var newEmail = new Model();
    newEmail.subject = email_object.subject;
    newEmail.body = email_object.body;
    newEmail.save(function(err) {
        if (err) console.error(err);
        console.log(count++);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem with for loop. Because the code inside the loop is asynchronous in nature. So I have used forEach instead of for. Please take a look at the following code. It works fine for me.

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    arr = [0, 1, 2];

arr.forEach(function(i) {
    var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/test' + i);

    conn.on('connected', function() {
        console.log('Mongoose connected to database', i);

        var Model = conn.model('Model', new mongoose.Schema({
            title: {
                type: String,
                default: 'model in test database'
            }
        }));

        var newModelA = new Model();
        newModelA.save({
            name: 'a'
        }, function(err) {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
            console.log('save A');
        });
    });
});
```

I have does this for three times. You can do it for 1000 times also.

Comment: `forEach` is synchronous, so this would behave the same as the OP's code.

Comment: In case of for loop as the inside code is asynchronous the loop will executes first then the code inside it will executes. So, the inside code will get the value of 2 in this case(above example). But in case of forEach loop it will not happen. I have run the OP's code as well as my own code. I request you to run the code you will also get the difference. Thank you.

Comment: OK, that will fix the shared `conn` variable problem, but it doesn't resolve the OP's `failed to connect` errors. That's coming from the fact that all 1000 of these connection pools are being opened in a synchronous loop.  Some async flow control is needed to address that.

Comment: I think 'failed to connect' problem is a different issue. It may be some problem with the OP's mongodb. Again I request you to run the code snippet, and you can easily find that the code is working as expected and producing result effectively.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the `failed to connect` error because you're creating all 1000 database connection pools in a synchronous loop which is exhausting the supply of available MongoDB connections.

So you need to introduce some asynchronous flow control to your approach using something like the [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async#asyncjs) library's [`eachLimit`](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachLimit) method:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var async = require('async');

var iterations = [];
for (var i = 0; i != 1000; i++) {
    iterations.push(i);
}

// Iterate over iterations, allowing no more than 5 async iterations to be
// outstanding at any one time.
async.eachLimit(iterations, 5, function(i, callback) {
    var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/test' + i);

    conn.on('connected', function(err) {
        console.log('Mongoose connected to database');

        var Model = conn.model('Model', new mongoose.Schema({
            title : { type : String, default : 'model in test database' }
        }));

        var newModelA = new Model();
        newModelA.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
            console.log('save A');

            // Close the connection and tell eachLimit this iteration is
            // complete by having the close method call the eachLimit callback
            // when the close completes.
            conn.close(callback);
        });    
    });
}, function() {
    console.log('All done!');
});
```