# How to use same model file for two or more DB Connections

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How to call multiple Database table in same Model JS File
Let's Say

```
var mongoose = require('./node_modules/mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/_db1');
module.exports = exports = mongoose;

// I know this overwrites
// Something like calling with different variable name
// Say mongoosedb1, mongoosedb2
// Still if do that we have to pass the library to both variables
// Any other possible ways??

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/_db2');
module.exports = exports = mongoose;
```

I am not sure whether this is making sense, Could you anyone please give some suggestions, I am new to this MEAN Stack framework.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474712/mongoose-and-multiple-database-in-single-node-js-project

Comment: No that is not my question :), That is under a single node project. I am asking to access for a signal JS file, which has the db connections, under model folder.

Comment: Are you possibly asking "How to use the same model on two database connections, within the same application?", which would seem a lot clearer title and a base for rethinking your explanation in your question. But I should also add that "technically" is not not the "model" that would be shared but the "schema" to "two" models, being one for each database connection.

Comment: Yeah well "just using the title I suggested" does not really make the question that much clearer in itself without clarifying the content a little bit. Also a "search engine" might even help you with the phrase as suggested in the title.