# Mongoose multiple connections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Currently I have this code for my connection **mongoose.js**:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var uriUtil = require('mongodb-uri');
var mongodbUri = 'mongodb://localhost/db_name';
var mongooseUri = uriUtil.formatMongoose(mongodbUri);
mongoose.connect(mongooseUri);
module.exports = mongoose;
```

File that requires the connection is **test.js**:

```
var mongoose = require('../model/mongoose');
var schema = mongoose.Schema({...});
```

---

---

How can I update mongoose.js to use multiple connections with mongoose.createConnection(...) function?

I start with changes only for one connection when I do changes like that:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/db_name');
mongoose.open('localhost');
module.exports = mongoose;
```

I get "undefined is not a function".
If I use this code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/db_name');
db.open('localhost');
module.exports = mongoose;
```

I get "Error: Trying to open unclosed connection"

Any advice?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Mongoose handling connections via *connections pool* 
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

You can use `server: {poolSize: 5}` option for increase/decrease pool (number of parallel connections)

If you need connections to different databases look here
[Mongoose and multiple database in single node.js project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474712/mongoose-and-multiple-database-in-single-node-js-project)

Example of multiple connections:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/db1');
var conn2 = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/db2');
var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({})
var model1 = conn.model('User', Schema);
var model2 = conn2.model('Item', Schema);
model1.find({}, function() {
   console.log("this will print out last");
});
model2.find({}, function() {
   console.log("this will print out first");
});
```

Comment: Yes, I need multiple DB connection. I saw this answer, but it still doesn't work in my case. Example with conn and conn2 looks the best but I can't just separate it to two files. Can you please try give an example with?

Comment: added working example for you. Is it what you needed?

Comment: In case it helps anyone, FYI don't use mongoose.model('User', Schema) like you might with connect (don't use mongoose.model); use connectionname.model as shown in the example

Comment: TypeError: conn.model is not a function if you get this error don't use `.then` or `.catch` on `createConnection` like you could with `connect`...

Comment: @AeroWang TY i stumbled for at least 30min before seeing your comment 

Comment: @vmkcom Great solution, thank you. Can you also describe how we can save a document to one of the connections?

Comment: Ah this works actually - we can use the `model()` method again like `const Item = conn2.model('Item', Schema);` and then create a `new` one like `const item = new Item({ // stuff to build the new document });`

Answer (score 11):

OK. With your example I found a solution that fit my needs.

**mongoose.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.main_conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/main');
mongoose.admin_conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/admin');
module.exports = mongoose;
```

**content.js**

```
var mongoose = require('../model/mongoose');
var schema = mongoose.Schema({...});

/// functions here
schema.statics.func_a(){...};
schema.statics.func_b(){...};

// And finaly updated only one line
//exports.Content = mongoose.model('Content', schema);
exports.Content = mongoose.main_conn.model('Content', schema);
```

The only thing, is it OK to add connection objects to mongoose object or may be there is more elegant solution.

Comment: And how we can close these connections as parallel?I get error `TypeError: client.s.dbCache[name].emit is not a function`

Answer (score 6):

**config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    default: 'main',
    main: 'mongodb://localhost/main',
    admin: 'mongodb://localhost/admin',
};
```

**connection.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('./config');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

function createConnection(name) {
    return mongoose.createConnection(config[name]);
}

module.exports = createConnection(config[config.default]);

module.exports.on = createConnection;
```

**model.js (custom class)**

```
const connection = require('./connection');

class Model {
    constructor(name, data) {
        this.data = data;
        return this.connection().model(name, data.schema);
    }

    connection() {
        if (this.data.connection) {
            return connection.on(this.data.connection);
        }

        return connection;
    }
}

module.exports = Model;
```

**user.js**

```
const Schema = require('mongoose').Schema;
const conn = require('./connection');
const Model = require('./model');

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    password: String
});

// USING MONGOOSE MODEL
// default connection
const UserM1 = conn.model('User', userSchema);

// admin connection
const UserM2 = conn.on('admin').model('User', userSchema);

// USING CUSTOM MODEL
// default connection
const UserC1 = new Model('User', { 
    schema: userSchema 
});

// admin connection
const UserC2 = new Model('User', { 
    schema: userSchema, 
    connection: 'admin' 
});
```

Comment: this is nice. Are you still using it now? Are there any cons to using this model?