# More than one Mongo endpoint in same API

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My **NodeJS** application has form with text input field (for search) and a dropdown **mongo** for DEV, UAT and Production database options.

Based on the user selection respective database has to be accessed.

I want to know how to **dynamically handle /change different database endpoint** or change node env in run-time ?

Answer (score 1):

One way that comes to my mind is to **disconnect and connect** again. If you are using mongoose, do something like:

```
   var mongoose = require('mongoose')
   ...
   try {
   mongoose.disconnect();
   mongoose.connect(mongoURL);
   catch (e) {
   console.log(e);
   }
```

every time and take the mongoURL from the user input.

Another way is to use **multiple connections**:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/db1');
var conn2 = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/db2');
```

and then choose the connection that you want to use depending on the user choice. **I prefer this last one.**

Take a look at this answer for more info:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32909008/7041393