# How can I handle database Models referencing to each other or being shared by different microservices?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, microservices, react-fullstack

I have a monolithic full stack app, that i am trying to refactor to a microservice architecture. In the monolithic architecture, I have the following models:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"
const itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    productType:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    itemImages: [{
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }],
    itemName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    itemStatus: {
        type: String,
        default: "Active"
    },
    itemPrice: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    itemDetails: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    author: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
})
const Item = mongoose.model("Item",itemSchema)
export default Item
```

and I have a user model

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    resetCode:{type: String},
    profilePic: {
        type: String,
        default:"../Assets/profilePic.jpg"
    },
    itemsLiked:[
        {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'Item'
        } 
      ],

    address: {
        type: String,
    },
})

const User = mongoose.model("User",userSchema)
export default User
```

Now, I am thinking making two of them as a separate microservices with their own database. However, I am caught up with how should i handle the two models which are referring to each other? so, how do i move forward with handling the models for each? thank you in advance.

Comment: Do answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906467/mongoose-multiple-connections) question or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57132253/mongoose-multiple-database-connections) one help?

Comment: @jQueeny i don't think you understood the question right. I am asking about how to use foreign keys in microservices not using multiple databases in the same service.

Comment: Don't look at the questions, look at the answers. You can use `mongoose.createConnection()` to create 2 different connections for your two different databases. Models can then be scoped to the single connection and you can just query each one independently. Referencing the `ObjectId` from one collection in database A to a collection in database B is trivial. However, when you `populate` you will need to pass the actual model in the options object as it will need to `$lookup` into the other database.

Comment: @jQueeny I did see that and I still don't think the solution given there don't answer the question or i don't think it's related at all

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** you don't establish explicit connections (like foreign keys) between the two schemas. The foreign IDs (userId in Item, and itemIds in User) become some ID that comes from any other external service.

With microservices you typically have one database per service. And because each service's database is an implementation detail of that service, you should not expose it, or any of its internals to the service's clients. Doing so would create a hard coupling between those services.

When microservices exchange data between them, and they store that data, they should treat it just like any other data that comes from an external system (be that one that you control, or something from a 3-party).

The implication of this approach is that you lose the consistency that your database provided for your data, as you no longer have that enforced through foreign keys of tables hosted in a single database. Enforcing that consistency needs to be done through business logic in the affected services.

Another approach you could take is storing whatever properties you need of the external entity, instead of relying on the ID to get the data from the external service. E.g. Item would only store the author's name (admittedly a poor example, as you may want to do things like 'get all items from this author', but I think the example works). This way, you reduce the need to maintain that consistency, as even if the external record was deleted in the User's database, you still keep the information you need in the Item service.