# How to use multiple MongoDB servers in a MEANJS project?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, meanjs

I am working on a MEANJS project where I need to connect with two different MongoDB server.

Currently, I am trying to disconnect from one server and connect to another but it says "Error: Trying to open unclosed connection.". I am using Mongoose module for db activity.

What is the approach to work with multiple Mongodb server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474712/mongoose-and-multiple-database-in-single-node-js-project

Comment: I do not want to create subfolder. I am creating another module with will use another Mongodb server.