# How insert data into multiple database at a time in MongoDb.

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, saas

I am very new to Mean Stack, I have a situation where I need to insert data into multiple database using mongoose. Can anyone help on this please.

Comment: please google it before asking here.

Comment: u should use monogo replica. google it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474712/mongoose-and-multiple-database-in-single-node-js-project

Answer (score 0):

use insertMany() function to insert multiple documents at time.