# Express.js: create additional mongodb DB in controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm new to MongoDB.

When I create my node.js server I use only one DB connection (on start I connect to it).
But imagine: I have one database with some generic tables, and more databases - each for a custom client.

How can I create those DB at runtime?

**start.js:**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

// import environmental variables from variables.env file
require("dotenv").config({ path: "variables.env" });

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connection.on("error", err => {
  console.error(` → ${err.message}`);
});

require("./models/MaintenanceType");
require("./models/Maintenance");

const app = require("./app");
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 7777);
const server = app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
  console.log('started');
});
```

**variables.env (example):**

```
NODE_ENV=development
DATABASE=mongodb://db:qwe123@sometest.server.com:412345/webtest
PORT=1234
SECRET=webtest
KEY=webtestcom
```

and controller:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Maintenance = mongoose.model("Maintenance");

exports.createMaintenance = async (req, res) => {
  const maintenance = await new Maintenance(req.body).save();
  // ALSO create a db and table if not exists for this client and use it somehow
  res.json(maintenance);
};
```

is it possible to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474712/mongoose-and-multiple-database-in-single-node-js-project

Comment: @rashad nope, totally different

Comment: Could you please explain the difference? I see in both questions it's asked to have connections to different databases. And there are 2 ways to do this as I described in my answer. Did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @rashad I have to use it as multi-tenancy schema

Comment: @rashad so db-s are dynamic. not a predifined project in a project
like this: https://gist.github.com/alancasagrande/23e6284e24dadafce8c0

Comment: Not sure I fully understand you. Isn't `useDb()` dynamic for you? ) You can get connection to another database and use it any time at any place in the code using `const dbCustom = db.useDb('newDb');`, and it's not predefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create new connection

```
mongoose.connect('URI_FOR_ANOTHER_DATABASE')
```

But it's bad idea to create new connections, so the driver has a feature to use existing connections to query another database, for this purpose you can check `useDb()` method as shown [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/wiki/3.8-Release-Notes#connection-pool-sharing)