# Mongoose query doesn't run when readyState is 1

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have written the following code, it's for a discord bot. When I call the command I get matchID in console for the first time. But when I call the command again I dont get any output. It gets stuck near the point where I have console.log("Stuck Here"). I new to mongoose so I don't know what to do.

```
if (mongoose.connection.readyState === 0) {
                mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost/${server}`, {
                    useNewUrlParser: true
                });
                console.log('mongoose readyState is ' + mongoose.connection.readyState);
            }

            console.log("Stuck here!");

            mongoose.connection.on("error", function (err) {
                console.log("Could not connect to mongo server!");
                return console.log(err);
            });

            mongoose.connection.on('connected', function (ref) {
                console.log('Connected to mongo server.');

                mongoose.connection.db.listCollections({
                    name: "matches"
                }).next(function (err, collinfo) {
                    if (err) console.log(err);

                    if (collinfo) {
                        Matches.findOne({}, {}, {
                            sort: {
                                'created_at': -1
                            }
                        }, function (err, match) {
                            if (err) console.log(err);

                            console.log(`${match.matchID}`);
                        })
                    } else {
                    }    
                });
            })
```

Comment: Your code seems overly complicated. I've never had the need to check the ready state of a connection, for instance: just call `mongoose.connect()` at the top of your code. Also, don't rely on certain events, like `connected`, before performing your queries (one reason for that, and the one you're probably running in to, is that those events only trigger _once_).

Comment: If I remove the event `connected` and just connect to database, the `mongoose.connection.db.listCollections` returns as `TypeError: Cannot read property 'listCollections' of undefined`

Comment: Why do you need `listCollections` at all?

Comment: On it's inital run there is no database, and bot will establish connection to a pseudo url. And it'll try to look for a collection name `matches` in it. If it doesnt find any, it'll insert a record, making the pseudo db an actual db. And if it already exists I'll get the latest entry from collection `matches` and fetch the last match number and increment it and insert a new record. I'm pretty new to this and this was the only way that came to my mind to execute it,

Comment: So you can have multiple database connections active at once? In that case, you have to be aware that even though Mongoose _can_ work with multiple databases, it isn't trivial to get working. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19475270), for instance: for each connection, you need to recreate all your models.

Comment: Yeah that was the plan but seeing the complexity and my skills I'll stick to single server.

Comment: A relatively simple solution would be to use a single database, and add a `server` field to all your models that you can include in each query. So to check if there's a `Matches` document for server "X", you'd run `Matches.findOne({ server : 'X' })`.

Comment: Ah like foreign keys, thanks for the idea and helping out! much appreciated. How do I mark the question answered?

Comment: I'll write up a proper answer :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose is really meant to be used with a single database. It isn't *impossible* to create create multiple connections, or use multiple database, but it's not trivial either. For instance, you have to declare each of your models for each connection/database (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19475270/893780), for instance).

It's probably much easier to use a single database, and adjust your models so they contain a property `server` that you can use as a key in all your queries.

So to check if there's a `Matches` document for server "X", you'd run `Matches.findOne({ server : 'X' })`.

You could also consider creating a separate model `Servers` that would store metadata for servers, and use references between the `Matches` and `Servers` models. More info on that [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).