# How to store a data in two different database in single node project with mongodb

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I want to store a data in two different database in node.I tired but its not working.

```
   // connect two databases
  mongoose.connect(
        keys.mongoURI
    );
    mongoose.connect(
        keys.mongoURI1 //connectivity link
    );

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const ServerPortRouter = express.Router();
const ServerPort = require('../models/ServerPort');
ServerPortRouter.route('/add').post(function (req, res) {
  const serverport = new ServerPort(req.body);
  serverport.save()
    .then(serverport => {
        res.json('Server added successfully');
    })
});
```

Data stored in single database, But I dont know to store this same data in two diffrent database

I am beginning to node I tired but I can't do this . Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474712/mongoose-and-multiple-database-in-single-node-js-project

Answer (score 0):

Try Creating separate models for each connection/database as below:

```
var conn      = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/testA');
var conn2     = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/testB');

// stored in 'testA' database
var ModelA    = conn.model('Model', new mongoose.Schema({
  title : { type : String, default : 'model in testA database' }
}));

// stored in 'testB' database
var ModelB    = conn2.model('Model', new mongoose.Schema({
  title : { type : String, default : 'model in testB database' }
}));
```

Comment: for schema structure its k, but I want save a into database