# Testing a multiple databases connections node.js app with Jest

Tags: node.js, mongoose, jestjs, multiple-databases

I have a node app that uses multiple databases. I created a separate connection and model for each database per the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474712/mongoose-and-multiple-database-in-single-node-js-project).

However, when I run my Jest unit tests for testing the validation methods on the model's schema, I get the following error (did not happen when I was using a single database, without calling createConnection()):

"Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?".
I understand that I'm getting this error since createConnection()is an async method.

My question is: how do I make both multiple databases and Jest work together?

Comment: have you closed all the database connections in the globalTeardown jest hook?