# Mongoose connect to multiple databases

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a node js application with many files. Three of them have the following declarations respectively:

```
mongoose2.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/terms");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/results");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/users");
```

The problem is that this for some reason does not work. The data are saved in database, but mongoose is confused and each time they are saved randomly among terms, results and users. Do you know why this is happening and a workaround maybe ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose and multiple database in single node.js project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474712/mongoose-and-multiple-database-in-single-node-js-project)

Comment: Make sure to read beyond the accepted answer on the linked answer, is [there is a better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19475270/2579117)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating 3 separate mongo connections it's better to switch between dbs using `useDb()` [method](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#connection_Connection-useDb).

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const termsConn = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://localhost:27017/terms");
//... code

const resultsConn = temmsConn.useDb("results");
console.log(resultsConn.name); // => results
```