# How to switch remote databases in nodejs while requesting data from frontend?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Lets say I've got multiple clients and few of them would like to connect their databases in order to get some data. Now they will store their credentials in the common database. When hitting some specific set of APIs I want to use those credentials to switch the databases and send data back to front-end.
How can I achieve this ?
Use case - Like in tableau we can connect our database and get data from it, I want to connect to a different database and fetch data from there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose and multiple database in single node.js project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474712/mongoose-and-multiple-database-in-single-node-js-project)

Comment: It does indeed.Thank you so much @whoami