# Connect two MONGO dbs on different port using mongoose in a node js app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, odm

I am having two mongodb dbs running on different port, how can I connect and do operations to these both dbs using mongoose.

I know we have createconnection feature to connect to different dbs but there they are supposed to be on same url like
`http://localhost:{port1}`
and then we use `mongoose.connect(http://localhost:{port1})` and then `mongoose.createconnection(http://localhost:{port1}/db1)` and `mongoose.createconnection(http://localhost:{port1}/db1)` to create two connections.

but my dbs are on `http://localhost:{port1}` and `http://localhost:{port2}`

how can I use mongoose to Connect two MONGO dbs on different port using mongoose in a node js app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose and multiple database in single node.js project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474712/mongoose-and-multiple-database-in-single-node-js-project)

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti I saw this. In this again we are connecting to same machine but I am having different ports.

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19475270/6303273, you can set multiple port on connections.
For example conn can be on portX and conn2 can be on portY.