# How can I dynamically set the database name for a Mongoose model in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

So i have a Question Model in mongoose:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please provide a question title'],
    unique: true
  },
  answers: {
    type: Array,
    required: [true, 'Please provide answers for the question'],
    unique: true
  },
  correctAnswer: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please provide correct answer']
  },
  type: {
    type: String,
    default: 'question'
  }
});
// function createModel(databaseName) {
//   return mongoose.model(databaseName, questionSchema);
// }
const Question= mongoose.model('Database', questionSchema);
module.exports = Question;
```

But the problem is that diffrent questions belong to diffrent databases. So in this:

```
  const Question= mongoose.model(**'Database'**, questionSchema);
    module.exports = Question;
```

Database should be a variable. So i can use the Question Model to build question but send them to diffrent databases. How to do it? If this should be a function, how to use it in Controller file?

Comment: You realise the first argument of mongoose.model is a model name, not a database name, yes? https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/d5964cdeeb278bf55b656fcf0217233b41e1e9ef/lib/index.js#L519  And it is just a string. Either hardcoded or a variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose and multiple database in single node.js project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474712/mongoose-and-multiple-database-in-single-node-js-project)

Comment: i mean diffrent collections in db, not diffrent databases 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what your end-goal is but you can explicitlly set the collection as the [third parameter](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#Mongoose.prototype.model()) of the `mongoose.model()` method and will stop mongoose from inferring  the collection from the model name (default behaviour):

```js
const Question = mongoose.model('Question', questionSchema, 'levelOneQuestions');
```

This can be done using a variable as well:

```js
const collection = someFunctionToDecideCollection();

const Question = mongoose.model('Question', questionSchema, collection);
```

A very simple example to illustrate how this would work is:

```js
app.get('/user/:id/questions', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
        if(user.level === 1){
           const Question = mongoose.model('Question', questionSchema, 'levelOneQuestions');
           const questions = await Question.find({});
        }else{
           //...
        }
        res.status(200).json({
           questions: questions
        });
    } catch(err) {
        next(err);
    }
});
```